# How can I upload notes to Pardot prospects and push them through to leads in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, pardot

In Salesforce I can see the Pardot Notes field on the Lead level but in Pardot when I go to Admin > Configure Fields > Prospect Fields  I do not see the Pardot Notes field (appears as Notes under Insight section when viewing prospect record).  How do I mass update this field on multiple prospects in Pardot through an upload and ensure it syncs over to the corresponding Salesforce leads?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation Pardot notes field is used for internal-only notes about a prospect.

What's more, Notes can be added, edited, and removed only from the individual prospect record, so probably you can't upload notes in batch (at least with a standard Pardot import).

Also, this field is not available for use in any forms, automations, or segmentation rules. It is available only on individual prospect records, so you won't be able to synchronize it with Salesforce.

**Solution:**

I would suggest creating a custom text-area field with a setting to accept multiple responses (just like standard Pardot Notes) and then synchronizing it with the field in Salesforce.